# Car is very sluggish to accelerate - Ford Territory

Tags: ford, fuel-system, acceleration

So car has bad acceleration,it's an Australian ford territory SY, feels worse when accelerating around a corner but still horribly weak going straight.

The instant fuel shows a jump to like 25-40l per 100 on any acceleration then will settle back to normal values but that's just from the trip computer.

So far I've replaced

- battery
- spark plugs
- coils
- upstream o2
- fuel pump
- fuel filter

Air filter looks clean and the throttle body been cleaned.

Alternator is charging bit low, around the 13.4v range but I honestly can't remember if that's how it's always been

I noticed this with old o2 and same with new one, the voltages get quite low, as low as around 0.075 fluctuating up between 0.800

The car seems to vibrate when rpm hits 1500. Very noticeable in park and raising it from idle

I was under the impression proper range is like 0.200 to 0.800, but this is dropping very lean.

I changed pump cus it was making a gargle sound and the trip wouldn't go down past 18l per 100km and the rpm would jump around at idle,since replacing no noise and sitting at 13 litres, no idle misfire.

But still very sluggish acceleration. Injectors are clicking louder than they did.

Im wondering about the fuel pressure regulator but I dunno.

I wonder if the actual problem caused the pump to wear out faster which is why it would misfire and make very loud gargling noise..

Car was fine, drove it on 4 hour trip, wasn't any issue then got home, car sat in drive way for two weeks, when I went to drive again, it's been like this since

It's a smidge better with new pump but definitely wasn't the issue.

No fault codes, no engine light etc.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What's the condition of the air filter?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for commenting. Yeah the filter was changed in 2020 but looks clean and healthy still. I noticed the intake temp gets high like 40/50c after like idling it for 10m. The air temp is in the map, so I'm wondering if the map sensor is bad but no fault code..